# Remove grafana from ubuntu 17.10

Tags: grafana, ubuntu-17.10

I'm trying to un-install grafana 4.6.3 from  Ubuntu 17.10, but is not possible. So far i have tried
`sudo apt-get remove grafana , sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove grafana` 
and says Unable to locate package grafana. 
Also tried to install it again from ubuntu software in order to unistall it properly but then pops me up an error message says: Unable to install grafana snap "graphana" is already installed. I installed it first time from ubuntu software.
What can i do to un-install it?

Comment: Wrong forum, SO is about programming, not Ubuntu administration.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried dpkg?

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <packagename>
```

If apt won't remove it try using dpkg.

You could also try and clean up your apt utility.

```
sudo rm -rf  /var/cache/apt/archives/<package_name.deb>
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```